# Simple encryption

Tags: java, encryption

I'm writing a simple encryption program. For all letters between 'A' & 'Z' and 'a' & 'z' I want to turn the alphabet so 'a' is 'z' and 'b' is 'y'.

This is what I have so far.

```
public static void deCrypt() {
    char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ".toCharArray();
    char[] crypt = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba ".toCharArray();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Mata in meddelandet: ");
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char temp = input.charAt(i);

        int tempNums = (new String(alphabet).indexOf(temp));
        System.out.print(new String(crypt).charAt(tempNums));
    }
}
```

The problem is that the program is not case sensitive, so if I type an uppercase or a (!) I get an error. I want to be able to type "GO go Go". Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about case, you can just do `input.toLowerCase()`

Comment: In addition to that, you can use `Character.isAlphabetic()` to check for characters other than letters so you can skip over punctuation. Although seeing that you want to include spaces, you'll have to check for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an if-statement checking that letter is a character.

You can use `"someString".matches("[ a-z]")` which will return true if it is a lower case character or a space and false otherwise. Similarly you can use regex `"[ A-Z]"` for uppercase.

You could do something like this:

```
public static void deCrypt() {
    String alphabetLowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";
    String alphabetUpperCase = alphabetLowerCase.toUpperCase();
    int length = alphabetLowerCase.length();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Mata in meddelandet: ");
    String input = scan.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);

        if (String.valueOf(c).matches("[ a-z]")) {
            System.out.print(alphabetLowerCase.charAt(length - alphabetLowerCase.indexOf(c)));
        } else if (String.valueOf(c).matches("[ A-Z]")) {
            System.out.print(alphabetUpperCase.charAt(length - alphabetUpperCase.indexOf(c)));
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that I didn't run this code, so the index might be off by 1 somewhere.

Comment: I need to include questionmarks aswell. Not only letters when i type in the string i want to encrypt?

Comment: Then you can just update that regex. By the way, you should include such requirements in your question...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `variablename*.equalsIgnoreCase(variablename*)`if you want it to not be case sensitive. There are alternatives like converting the string beforehand to normalize it.

As Lidae noted, `input.toLowerCase()` would accomplish normalization fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it

```
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String input = "Go go GO";
    for(int i=0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        int index = alphabet.indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)));
        if (index == -1) {
            System.out.print(input.charAt(i));
            continue;
        }
        char encrypted = alphabet.charAt(25 - index);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(input.charAt(i))) {
            System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(encrypted));
        } else {
            System.out.print(encrypted);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply turn the input into lowercase and only encrypt the alphabetic characters when looping through the string. You don't need the alphabet string too in this case. Just subtract 'a' from the character to get the index.

```
String crypt = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Mata in meddelandet: ");
String input = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();

for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
      char ch = input.charAt(i);
      if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
           ch = crypt.charAt((int)(ch - 'a'));
      }                                                                                                                                         
      System.out.print(ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a private function to do what you want:

```
private String encrypt(String input) {
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";
    List<Character> list = alphabet.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());
    String output = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        output += list.get(list.size() - list.indexOf(input.toLowerCase().charAt(i)) -1);
    }
    return output;
}
```

It converts your string of alphabet characters to a list and loops through your input, collecting the opposite order from list and returns the encoded output string.
Requires Java 8.

Use it like this:

```
encrypt("GO go GO") // Returns "umaumaum"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by substracting the int-value of your char from 122 and add 'a' or 'A' depending on your char is uppercase or lowercase.

```
public static String deCrypt(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++){
        sb.append((char)(122-str.toLowerCase().charAt(i)+ ((Character.isLowerCase(str.charAt(i)))?'a':'A')));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to implement a Ceasar Cipher, unless its academic I suggest you just lookup an implementation for yourself.

http://practicalcryptography.com/ciphers/caesar-cipher/

Comment: OP is not implementing Ceasar Cipher. He is not just shifting all characters. For given key, encrypt character at position `x` in the key into character at position `length - x` in the key.

Comment: You're right, he's not implementing a general Ceasar Cipher, however it still is a Ceasar Cipher, just a special case.  A general purpose implementation could do what he wants as well handle case and punctuation.